# solr search with wildcard doesnt return document with just prefix text

Tags: solr, wildcard, prefix, edismax

I'm doing a Solr edismax search for **A** with a wildcard
hoping to get back 'A' and anything following it
code query example:

```
query?q=A*&qf=Field1^1.0 Field2^0.8 Field3^0.5&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&rows=20
```

what i get back is 
[{A.},{A..},{A...}]

i expect to get back 
[{**A**},{A.},{A..}]

why isnt **A** returned as a result?

Comment: using the query 
    ?q=(A OR A*)
gives me back [{A}, {A..}, {A...}, ...]
there has to be a better way of doing this

Comment: if i search ?q=AAA then one of the results is AAA
[{AAA.}, {AAA}, {AAAA}]
looks like the issue is that i need the prefix to take precedence to other results

Comment: Is A being filtered as a stop word?  Also since A is so common it might get a lower score and get pushed further down.

Comment: i dont have any other params than what you see in the query. from my testing, i think as you said, A has a lower score and is not in the top 20.  any idea how to give it a higher score?

Comment: ?q=(A^9999 OR A*)   this is query boosting, the term a should come up the the top

Comment: Vince that works but AA doesn't follow next.  the order of the fields is not alpha sorted.  ex. i see A, AX, AI, AB, AL...

Comment: I don't know of anything that exists for solr to do that.  You could sort by a field rather than scoring, but that still won't accomplish what you are looking for.  Sorry.